# Calculate the limit using de L'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits

Calculate the following limit:

$\lim_{x \to +\infty}(\sqrt{x}-\log x)$

I started like this:

$\lim_{x \to +\infty}(\sqrt{x}-\log x)=[\infty-\infty]=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{(x-(\log x)^2)}{(\sqrt{x}+\log x)}=$

but that's not a good way...

I would be gratefull for any tips.

Comment: Do you really need L'Hospital's rule for this limit? It's a high-school exercise.

Comment: You just need to take $\sqrt{x} $ as a factor and use $(\log x) /\sqrt{x} \to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

If you have to use l'Hôpital; this limit is easier to find (*):
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x} 
= \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}} =\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} = +\infty$$
Can you see how this would help for your limit as well?

If not (hoover over), rewrite:

> $$\sqrt{x}-\log x = \left( \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x} - 1 \right) \log x$$

---

(*) With a similar calculation, it's easy to show and worth remembering that for $n>0$:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x^n}{\log x} = +\infty$$

Comment: Thanks. So I have: $\sqrt(x)-log(x)=(\frac{\sqrt(x)}{logx}-1)log(x)=\frac{\frac{\sqrt(x)}{logx}-1}{1/log(x)}$ and it is $+\infty/ 0$, I still don't know what is next

Comment: No need to go further than $\left( \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x} - 1 \right) \log x$ since (obviously) $\log x \to +\infty$ and by our earlier l'Hôpital, also $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x} \to +\infty$; you see?

Comment: Ok, we get two factors both going to $+\infty$ so the product of them goes to $+\infty$. Right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Correct! And you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x \to +\infty}(\sqrt{x}-\log(x))=[\infty-\infty]=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{(x-\log(x)^2)}{(\sqrt{x}+\log(x))}=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt x-\frac{log(x)^2}{\sqrt x}}{\frac{\log x}{\sqrt x}+1}$

$-\frac{\log(x)^2}{\sqrt x}$ and $\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt x}$ both tend to zero as $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Then your limit is $\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt x=+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}(\sqrt{x}-\log x)$$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}
   \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-\log x}{1} 
   \cdot 
   \dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\log x}{\sqrt{x}+\log x}
   \right)$$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}
   \left( 
   \dfrac{x-(\log x)^2}{\sqrt{x}+\log x}
   \right)$$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}
   \left( 
   \dfrac{1-\frac{2\log x}{x}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}+\frac 1x}
   \right) \to \dfrac 10\to \infty$$